# Using a String and int properties in an enum class

Tags: java

I am using an enum for my configuration property file, so there are some values which are retrieved as string and others as int. Now I have two constructors for this and it works, I am just curious is there smarter way to solve this (sure there is). Actually this means that the class which uses this enum must know when to use the defaultValue or the defaultAmount..

```
public enum TestEnum {

CONFIG_USER("config.foobar.user", "dude"),
CONFIG_PASSWORD("config.foobar.password", "forgetIt"),
MAX_RETRIES("config.foobar.maxRetries", 30),
CONSUMER_THREADS("config.foobar.threads", 2);

private final String property;
private String defaultValue;
private int defaultAmount;


TestEnum(final String property, String defaultValue) {
    this.property = property;
    this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
}

TestEnum(final String property, final int amount) {
    this.property = property;
    this.defaultAmount = amount;
}

public String getProperty() {
    return property;
}

public String getDefaultValue() {
    return defaultValue;
}

public int getDefaultAmount() {
    return defaultAmount;
}
```

}

Comment: This model seems weak. Why do you need two different models represented by the same class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep only one field of the value and will handle the conversions internally. This way, the user of this class has only one method to use when he wants to get the value.

Something like this (not tested):

```
public enum TestEnum {

    CONFIG_USER("config.foobar.user", "dude"),
    CONFIG_PASSWORD("config.foobar.password", "forgetIt"),
    MAX_RETRIES("config.foobar.maxRetries", 30),
    CONSUMER_THREADS("config.foobar.threads", 2);

    private final String property;
    private String value;


    TestEnum(final String property, String defaultValue) {
        this.property = property;
        this.value = defaultValue;
    }

    TestEnum(final String property, final int amount) {
        this.property = property;
        this.value = "" + amount;       // <-------
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Edited: `value` field makes more sense to be a `String`, it's more general in a configuration context that has property-value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an interface to define common behavior:

```
interface TestEnum {
    public String getProperty();

    public String getDefaultValue();

    public int getDefaultAmount();
}
```

And then use two different enums for each type:

```
enum StringEnum implements TestEnum {
    ...
}

enum IntegerEnum implements TestEnum {
    ...
}
```